# Wordpress page content variable

Tags: wordpress

I am new to wordpress coding but familiar with standard HTML/CSS. With the help of various online tutorials I've finally gotten a good chunk of a simple HTML/CSS website converted to wordpress but Im missing out on some of the basics.

In this case, I am just trying to setup my template to work with the page.php file so that I can create pages through the wordpress admin console. I've figured out how to get the head.php, footer.php, and functions.php working for styles and js files but now I am struggling with what variable I need to place so that the title and content I enter into the page via the wordpress admin appears.

I've tried

1) using a div id=content to my page.php file --that didnt work
2) I've tried adding  to my page.php file -- that didnt work

I cant seem to figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am a definitley a beginner here so any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a very basic template of a `page.php` in Wordpress.

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

    <div>
            <?php
            if( have_posts() ) :
                while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

                   the_title(); // Outputs the title of the page
                   the_content(); // Outputs the content of the page


                endwhile; // End of the loop. 
            endif;
            ?>

    </div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Also, if you would like to store the title and content in php variables first, you can just call `get_the_title()` and `get_the_content()`

Please let me know if you are stuck.